# epson-printer-utility error loading shared libraries

Tags: software-installation, qt, 20.04

When trying to run the printer utility I downloaded from Epson website I get the following error:

```
epson-printer-utility: error while loading shared libraries: libQtCore.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I presume this is because the QT4 libraries aren't installed on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. And it seems no longer available to install.

I have googled and tried installing various QT4 libraries by various means without success. For example:

```
$ sudo apt-get install qt4-default
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package qt4-default is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'qt4-default' has no installation candidate
```

Help please.

I'm new to linux so be kind and very specific with what I need to do!

Comment: Will installing QT5 help? I thought the printer utility was looking specifically for the QT4 libraries (libQtCore.so.4)?

Comment: Still no joy. I installed qt5-default in desperation but epson-printer-utility still looking for libQtCore.so.4. Can anyone help me please???

Comment: Can anyone help me with installing qt4 on 20.04 please? How do I configure Ubuntu to find the old binaries/libraries?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Ubuntu 20.04 LTS no longer has Qt4 libraries on purpose.** See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233471/lack-of-qt4-qtconfig-pakage-in-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa), for instance. Your best bet is [compiling from source](https://www.ics.com/blog/how-compile-qt-source-code-linux), or [setting up a virtual machine](https://www.howtogeek.com/117635/how-to-install-kvm-and-create-virtual-machines-on-ubuntu/) with an older Ubuntu version as the guest OS.

Or, if you're feeling adventurous, you can add [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~rock-core/+archive/ubuntu/qt4), then install Qt4:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qt4-default
```

This removes `qt5-default` from your system. Let's add it back:

```
sudo apt install qt5-default
```

Now you have both Qt4 and Qt5 libraries installed in your system in a *fragile* balance. The Qt4 libraries will be removed the next time you run `sudo apt autoremove` to clean up installed packages. Let's prevent that from happening:

```
sudo apt install libodbc1 libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-designer libqt4-dev libqt4-dev-bin libqt4-help libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-opengl-dev libqt4-qt3support libqt4-script libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-odbc libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtcore4 libqtdbus4 libqtgui4 qdbus qt4-linguist-tools qt4-qmake qtcore4-l10n
```

Comment: This is the only solution which worked for an Epson Eco-Tank L1110 in order to properly run the epson-printer-utility. Thank you

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo I have an EcoTank ET-2720 myself. Glad to help!

Comment: worked for old Epson L355

Comment: What steps are needed to use this on Ubuntu 22.04? It does not work by default.

Answer (score 6):

The following worked for me on **Ubuntu 20.10** for `epson-printer-utility_1.1.1-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb`

Download the following `bionic` packages:
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qt4-x11/libqtcore4_4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1_amd64.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qt4-x11/libqtgui4_4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1_amd64.deb

Extract from them the following files:

```
libQtCore.so.4.8.7
libQtGui.so.4.8.7
```

Copy these two files to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. Assuming that folder with the files mentioned above is current folder in terminal:

```
sudo cp libQtCore.so.4.8.7 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
sudo cp libQtGui.so.4.8.7 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

Make appropriate symbolic links in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`:

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
sudo ln -s libQtCore.so.4.8.7 libQtCore.so.4
sudo ln -s libQtGui.so.4.8.7 libQtGui.so.4
```

The above makes **Epson Printer Utility** up and running. But its functionality is... Well, it is disappointing. All the functions provided can be performed on the device itself.
[image: Epson Printer Utility main window]

N.B. The following message does not seem to harm the application.

> Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"

It can be fixed by installation of `overlay-scrollbar-gtk2` package:

```
sudo apt install overlay-scrollbar-gtk2
```

Comment: this solution worked for me, but I also had to download libaudio package from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nas/libaudio2_1.9.4-6_amd64.deb and repeat the copy libaudio process to the same dir. By the way, I'm on ubuntu 21.10.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the libqt4 packages for the previous release, extract them, and tell `epson-printer-utility` to use them by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  I made a script:

https://gist.github.com/derde/025a1cdbfadc3e56dc6a46093d922c32

```
#! /bin/bash
  
  # Run epson-printer-utility from epson-printer-utility_1.0.2-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
  # using downloaded libqt4 libraries from previous Ubuntu version (not provided
  # in Ubuntu 20.04 "focal fossa"
  #
  # This downloads the deb files and extracts them in a libs directory in the
  # current directory, and then runs the utility
  #
  # Fix for:
  # epson-printer-utility: error while loading shared libraries: libQtCore.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  
  DEBS='
      http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qt4-x11/libqtgui4_4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu3_amd64.deb
      http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qt4-x11/libqtcore4_4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu3_amd64.deb
  '
  cd `dirname $0`
  mkdir -p libs
  cd libs
  
  echo "## `pwd`"
  if ! [ -f data.tar.zx ] ; then
      for DEB in $DEBS; do
          FILE="${DEB/*\/}"
          [ -f "$FILE" ] && continue
          echo "## download $DEB"
          wget $DEB
          echo "## extract $FILE"
          ar x $FILE
          tar -xJf data.tar.xz
          rm control.tar.xz  data.tar.xz debian-binary
      done
  fi
  
  echo "## run epson-printer-utility with `pwd`"
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`/./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu epson-printer-utility
```

Comment: Thanks for this. One step forward. But another error now... epson-printer-utility: error while loading shared libraries: libaudio.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: See if you can get another copy of `epson-printer-utility_1.0.2-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb`
I got one from here ...
http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule
It does not link to `libaudio.so.2`, as shown by `ldd /opt/epson-printer-utility/bin/epson-printer-utility`

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to answer to [@user6031769](https://askubuntu.com/users/1099641/user6031769), so I'll answer here. `libaudio.so.2` is required by the `libs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4` dowloaded by the script. I could not find answer on where to find this shared library with a quick search on the internet.

Comment: @ppom thanks for the useful comment! You can ask a new question about this if you don't get a response here - just add a link to this post in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem without using a PPA.

I downloaded three packages from `bionic` repo:

```
libqtcore4_4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libqtgui4_4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libaudio2_1.9.4-6_amd64.deb
```

and extracted these files using Archive manager:

```
libQtCore.so.4
libQ4Core.so.4.8.7
libQtGui.so.4
libQtGui.so.4.8.7
libaudio.so.2
```

then copied all 5 files to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Comment: I had to extract and copy libaudio.so.2.4 too. But on running the epson utility I get:epson-printer-utility: error while loading shared libraries: libaudio.so.2: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
Any idea how to fix that please?

Comment: Actually the ELF class error was probably because I downloaded that archive for Ubuntu 20.04. I found libaudio2_1.9.4-6_amd64.deb for 18.04 and now I get another error: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
At this rate I'm going to go back to using Windows 10. Help please!

Comment: You need to download all packages for 18.04.

Comment: To solve this problem I only had to install libqtcore4 and libqtgui4 using sudo apt install libqtcore4 libqtgui4