# Lack of qt4-qtconfig package in Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa

Tags: package-management, fonts, 20.04, qt4

I use an application called Mame Set Rebuilder (you can easily find references on internet) that is built in Qt4 in a .app format.

When I had Ubuntu 19.10, I was able to set the fonts of the application using the package `qt4-qtconfig`. Setting the fonts with this package prevents the app from using some predefined and ugly fonts.

Now I have a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 installation and the package has been removed from repository (and if I try to install it from a deb package, it requires some incompatible dependencies). The configurator for QT5 apps `qt5ct` seems not to be able to apply its configuration to QT4 apps.

Is there a way to improve the fonts of QT4 apps in focal fossa? Please consider that the app fully works, it's only an aestetic matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround. I created a VM with Ubuntu 19.10 and installed `qt4-qtconfig` package.
What the `qt4-qtconfig` tool does is to append some lines to the `~/.config/Trolltech.conf` file. According to my settings, the content is the following:

```
[Qt]
font="Ubuntu,11,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0"
Palette\active=#3d3d3d, #f5f6f7, #ffffff, #cbc7c4, #cccdce, #b8b5b2, #5d5d5d, #ffffff, #3d3d3d, #ffffff, #f5f6f7, #bdbdbe, #e95420, #ffffff, #0000ff, #ff00ff, #ffffff, #000000, #ffffdc, #ffffff
Palette\inactive=#3d3d3d, #f5f6f7, #ffffff, #cbc7c4, #cccdce, #b8b5b2, #5d5d5d, #ffffff, #3d3d3d, #ffffff, #f5f6f7, #bdbdbe, #e95420, #ffffff, #0000ff, #ff00ff, #ffffff, #000000, #ffffdc, #ffffff
Palette\disabled=#99999a, #f5f6f7, #ffffff, #cbc7c4, #cccdce, #b8b5b2, #99999a, #ffffff, #99999a, #ffffff, #f5f6f7, #bdbdbe, #e9e9e9, #ffffff, #0000ff, #ff00ff, #ffffff, #000000, #ffffdc, #ffffff
fontPath=@Invalid()
embedFonts=true
style=GTK+
doubleClickInterval=400
cursorFlashTime=1000
wheelScrollLines=3
resolveSymlinks=false
globalStrut\width=0
globalStrut\height=0
useRtlExtensions=false
XIMInputStyle=On The Spot
DefaultInputMethod=xim
audiosink=Auto
videomode=Auto
GUIEffects=none
```

In this way, QT4 applications have a nicer appearance.

Answer (score 4):

It's a [conscious decision](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2019-August/040783.html). The maintainer of the application should port it to qt5. You may want to ask them if there is an interest to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. the link you posted is very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

If you're fine installing from PPA's, [here's one](https://launchpad.net/~rock-core/+archive/ubuntu/qt4) that provides Qt4 for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Good to know, especially for other users that are interested in the full library. Thanks.