# Epson Printer Utility - shared libraries

Tags: printing, shared-library, epson

It seems programm doesn't find shared libraries:

angelou@angelou-Inspiron-5770:/$ **epson-printer-utility**

epson-printer-utility: error while loading shared libraries: libQtCore.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How to add LibQtCore.so.4  ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [epson-printer-utility error loading shared libraries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233178/epson-printer-utility-error-loading-shared-libraries)

Comment: You have two options. I would recommend my answer, because it doesn't break anything and installs only required files.