# Dependency problems prevent configuration of epson-printer-utility:i386 ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, dpkg, epson, lsb-release

i am trying to install the epson printer utilities with the hope i could use the Power Ink Flushing functionality since my printer L3151 will only print black and magenta

this is the error i get when trying to install the .deb package i downloaded from the espon website

```
$ sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/epson-printer-utility_1.1.1-1lsb3.2_i386.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package epson-printer-utility:i386.
(Reading database ... 330447 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../epson-printer-utility_1.1.1-1lsb3.2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking epson-printer-utility:i386 (1.1.1-1lsb3.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of epson-printer-utility:i386:
 epson-printer-utility:i386 depends on lsb (>= 3.2).

dpkg: error processing package epson-printer-utility:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 epson-printer-utility:i386
```

```
$ lsb_release -a

LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

i don't understand why i am getting this error :( i did some digging around but nothing useful appeared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue, as you're trying to install the 32-bit drivers (i386) on a 64-bit installation of Ubuntu. As a result, the dependency chain may be looking for a large number of 32-bit libraries, which are no longer available.

Using [the documentation from Epson](http://download.ebz.epson.net/man/linux/utility.html) regarding this package, the utility is installed like this:

1. Download the 64-bit package [from the Epson website](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=144817&DSCCHK=8252a842a2a960c5580b05493ea0d4b373886fd9). This would be the file named:

   ```
   epson-printer-utility_1.1.1-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Install the required LSB package:

   0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
   1. Make sure `apt` is updated:

      ```
      sudo apt update
      ```
   2. Install the package:

      ```
      sudo apt install lsb
      ```
3. Install the `.deb` package that was downloaded in Step 1:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i epson-printer-utility_1.1.1-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
   ```
4. Launch the utility:

   ```
   epson-printer-utility
   ```

I do not have an Epson printer to test the effectiveness of the utility, but the first four steps will work just fine on Ubuntu 20.04 and the newer 22.04.

Comment: thanks for your detailed and thorough response :) while i managed to install the amd64 version, yes i am on a 64 bit OS but i assumed the amd was referring to the CPU. unfortunately i am getting a new error :( 

epson-printer-utility: error while loading shared libraries: libQtCore.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. 

which apparently has been removed from the main ubuntu repo as it has reached end of life according to this post https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/07/install-qt4-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1305393/1222991) may give you enough to solve the issue 

Comment: the suggestions in that answer did not really help i just included the PPA ppa:gezakovacs/ppa and installed the qt4 packages but it cannot find my printer and most importantly it is was the feature i wanted in the first place. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you use `dpkg` directly to install or remove packages, it may fail with something, like dependencies in your case. What you can try to do is use `apt` to resolve the issue:

```
sudo apt -f install
```

It should install the packages that are required for the one you tried to install with `dpkg`, and lastly do just that if the requirements were satisfied.